Get 12 month running total for subgroups in Oracle
I'm trying to get a running 12 month total for data, but changing when values in my fields change.  I've made a simpler sql fiddle, for a 3 month running total, for one value in the table.  I'm stuck on two parts: 1) how to get the running total, but have it change each time my field values change, and 2) how to then write that running total back to my table.  (Or, I guess I could have a 2nd table and write to that instead.  Yeah, that's probably easier.)
-- INIT database
CREATE TABLE Product (
  Bill_Date         DATE,
  LGroup            VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),
  District          VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  MonthTot          NUMBER(15,4),
  Last12Tot         NUMBER(18,4)
);

INSERT INTO Product(Bill_Date, LGroup, District, MonthTot) VALUES (to_date('05/01/2022','MM/DD/YYYY'), 'Sam','West', 13);
INSERT INTO Product(Bill_Date, LGroup, District, MonthTot) VALUES (to_date('06/01/2022','MM/DD/YYYY'), 'Sam','West', 10);
INSERT INTO Product(Bill_Date, LGroup, District, MonthTot) VALUES (to_date('07/01/2022','MM/DD/YYYY'), 'Sam','West', 11);
INSERT INTO Product(Bill_Date, LGroup, District, MonthTot) VALUES (to_date('08/01/2022','MM/DD/YYYY'), 'Sam','West', 8);
INSERT INTO Product(Bill_Date, LGroup, District, MonthTot) VALUES (to_date('05/01/2022','MM/DD/YYYY'), 'Chi','West', 21);
INSERT INTO Product(Bill_Date, LGroup, District, MonthTot) VALUES (to_date('06/01/2022','MM/DD/YYYY'), 'Chi','West', 19);
INSERT INTO Product(Bill_Date, LGroup, District, MonthTot) VALUES (to_date('07/01/2022','MM/DD/YYYY'), 'Chi','West', 15);
INSERT INTO Product(Bill_Date, LGroup, District, MonthTot) VALUES (to_date('08/01/2022','MM/DD/YYYY'), 'Chi','West', 11);
INSERT INTO Product(Bill_Date, LGroup, District, MonthTot) VALUES (to_date('05/01/2022','MM/DD/YYYY'), 'Emi','East', 8);
INSERT INTO Product(Bill_Date, LGroup, District, MonthTot) VALUES (to_date('06/01/2022','MM/DD/YYYY'), 'Emi','East', 5);
INSERT INTO Product(Bill_Date, LGroup, District, MonthTot) VALUES (to_date('07/01/2022','MM/DD/YYYY'), 'Emi','East', 6);
INSERT INTO Product(Bill_Date, LGroup, District, MonthTot) VALUES (to_date('08/01/2022','MM/DD/YYYY'), 'Emi','East', 4);

-- QUERY database
SELECT * FROM Product;
-- this will do a running total for one group
SELECT bill_date, LGroup, District, MonthTot
     , sum(MonthTot) over (order by bill_date, LGroup, District rows between 2 preceding and current row) as Last12Tot
from (
  select bill_date, LGroup, District, MonthTot
  from Product
  where LGroup = 'Sam'
      )
order by LGroup, District, bill_date
;

So my data set will look something like this:
BILL_DATE   LGROUP  DISTRICT    MONTHTOT
01-MAY-22   Sam     West        13   
01-JUN-22   Sam     West        10   
01-JUL-22   Sam     West        11   
01-AUG-22   Sam     West        8    
01-MAY-22   Chi     West        21   
01-JUN-22   Chi     West        19   
01-JUL-22   Chi     West        15   
01-AUG-22   Chi     West        11   
01-MAY-22   Emi     East        8    
01-JUN-22   Emi     East        5    
01-JUL-22   Emi     East        6    
01-AUG-22   Emi     East        4   

My current query returns this:
BILL_DATE   LGROUP  DISTRICT    MONTHTOT    LAST12TOT
01-MAY-22   Sam     West        13          13
01-JUN-22   Sam     West        10          23
01-JUL-22   Sam     West        11          34
01-AUG-22   Sam     West        8           29

I will not have one LGroup in multiple Districts, so LGroup is essentially what I need to group by. There isn't a primary key - it's already data assembled from a query to get the totals for each month for each person and district.
Every time I try to get all the groups, my partitioning is not working at all.  I have multiple years and want a 12 month rolling total, but only within each group.
Once I have this, I can just sum my group totals to get district totals.

Use PARTITION BY and a RANGE window:
SELECT bill_date,
       LGroup,
       District,
       MonthTot,
       sum(MonthTot) over (
         PARTITION BY LGroup
         ORDER BY bill_date
         RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '11' MONTH PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
       ) AS Last12Tot
FROM   Product
order by LGroup, District, bill_date;

Which, for the sample data, outputs:



BILL_DATE
LGROUP
DISTRICT
MONTHTOT
LAST12TOT




2022-05-01 00:00:00
Chi
West
21
21


2022-06-01 00:00:00
Chi
West
19
40


2022-07-01 00:00:00
Chi
West
15
55


2022-08-01 00:00:00
Chi
West
11
66


2022-05-01 00:00:00
Emi
East
8
8


2022-06-01 00:00:00
Emi
East
5
13


2022-07-01 00:00:00
Emi
East
6
19


2022-08-01 00:00:00
Emi
East
4
23


2022-05-01 00:00:00
Sam
West
13
13


2022-06-01 00:00:00
Sam
West
10
23


2022-07-01 00:00:00
Sam
West
11
34


2022-08-01 00:00:00
Sam
West
8
42



fiddle

I'm sometimes getting a duplicate record on my month 12 entries, so I need to figure that out, but thank you!  I had tried partitioning, but obviously I had something else wrong when I tried that.  The 'interval month' is helpful, too.

But the duplicates just mean I don't have clean enough data (because obviously my data is way more complex than this example).  This is good!
